# What would be definition of "career" in "The Feast or Famine Careers"?

Tags: meaning

In this NYTimes Headline:

"‘No Jobs Available’: The Feast or Famine Careers of America’s Port Drivers"

do "Careers" means something other than profession/occupation?

can't wrap my head around this sentence.

Comment: feast or famine is an idiom. Here, used adjectivally.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence uses 'Feast or Famine', to describe the type of careers they are talking about. Careers where work is either abundant or non-existent.

'Careers' has its usual meaning, but the preceding nouns are being used as describers.

Answer (score 1):

In this context "careers" is, in fact, a profession or occupation. "Feast or Famine" description refers to the volume of work available. In a "Feast or Famine Career" the available work is inconsistent with very busy periods followed by periods with little or no available work. Workers either have WAY too much to do or they can't find work at all.